# The density of a solid half-sphere of radius $R$ is proportional to the distance from the symmetry axis. Find its center of mass

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

> - The density of a solid half-sphere of radius $R$ is proportional to the distance from the symmetry axis. Find its center of mass.

**Background for the Problem:** Suppose a solid object has the shape of a region $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and its mass density function is $\rho,$ so that the total mass of the object is
$$
M=\int_{E} \rho(x) d x
$$
The center of mass of this object is the point $p$ whose $k$ th coordinate is given by
$$
p^{k}=\frac{1}{M} \int_{E} x^{k} \rho(x) d x
$$
where $x^{k}$ is the $k$ th coordinate function (in other words, $p^{k}$ is the weighted average of the $k$ th coordinates of the points of $E$ ). The moment of inertia of a particle of mass $m$ with respect to a given axis is $m r^{2}$ where $r$ is the distance of the particle to the axis.

**My Attempt:** $$M=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}c r^3 sin\phi cos\phi dr d\theta d\phi=c2\pi \dfrac{R^4} {4}.$$

x coordinate: $$\dfrac{1} {M} (\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}x r^3 sin\phi cos\phi dr d\theta d\phi )$$

as $x=rsin\phi cos\theta$

$$=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}rsin\phi cos\theta r^3 sin\phi cos\phi dr d\theta d\phi=\int_0^{2\pi}cos\theta d\theta=0$$

y coordinate: $$\dfrac{1} {M} (\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}y r^3 sin\phi cos\phi dr d\theta d\phi)$$

$$=\dfrac{1} {M} (\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}rsin\phi cos\theta r^3 sin\phi cos\phi dr d\theta d\phi),$$

as $y=rsin\phi cos\theta$

$$=\int_0^{2\pi}sin\theta d\theta=0$$

z coordinate: $$\dfrac{1} {M} (\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}cz r^3 sin\phi cos\phi dr d\theta d\phi )=\dfrac{1} {M} (\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}c r^4 sin\phi cos^2\phi dr d\theta d\phi )$$

as $z=rcos\phi$

$$=c\dfrac{1} {3}2\pi \dfrac{R^5} {5} $$

Thus, z coordinate: $\frac{c  \frac{1}{3}  2\pi  \frac{R^{5}}{5}}{c  2 \pi  \frac{R^{4}}{4}}=\frac {4} {15}R.$

**Can you check my attempt? Could you add answer for this question? Thanks...**

Comment: Your answers look correct. But there was a faster way to do the $x$ and the $y$ integrals, by noting that the integrands were odd functions over a region that had equal amounts of $x$ and $-x$ (or $y$ and $-y$). While the $z$ integral was also an odd function, the region only contains positive $z$.

Comment: I take that back, your density function is wrong. Even though you didn't write it (and it was extremely annoying to parse out!) it seems like you used $\rho(x,y,z) = cz = cr\cos\phi$ but that is incorrect. The question says the density is proportional to the distance away from the symmetry axis of a hemisphere, that would be the radial coordinate in cylindrical coordinates so it should really be $\rho(x,y,z) = c\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = cr\sin\phi$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks, can you write answer below?

Comment: @NinadMunshi z coordinate should be $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{r} c^{2} r^{4} \sin (\phi) d r d \theta d \phi=\frac{2 \pi c^{2} r^{5}}{5}$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the correction I noted in the comments, the mass is

$$M = c \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^R r^3\sin^2\phi \:dr \:d\phi \:d\theta = c\frac{\pi^2R^4}{8}$$

The $x$ and $y$ coordinates are $0$ by odd function symmetry. The $z$ integral is

$$c\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^R r^4 \sin^2\phi \cos\phi \:dr\:d\phi\:d\theta = c\frac{2\pi R^5}{15}$$

making the center of mass

$$\text{c.o.m.} = (\bar{x}, \bar{y}, \bar{z}) = \left(0,0,\frac{16}{15\pi}R\right)$$